# Confusion on Which Tomcat JDBC (tomcat-jdbc) Driver to Use

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat-jdbc

## TL;DR:

How do we know which version of the tomcat-jdbc driver we need to use for a specific version of Tomcat?

Is there any reasonable documentation?

## Longer Version

Over the years I have looked for a reasonable explanation on which tomcat-jdbc driver to use with a specific version of Tomcat.  But I just haven't been able to find anything that says "For this version of tomcat, use this version of tomcat-jdbc driver."

My gut feeling is that the tomcat-jdbc version should be the same version as the tomcat server we're running.  Is that a true statement?

Meaning, if we're running tomcat 9.0.65 we should be using the tomcat-jdbc 9.0.65?

Are there any links out there that specifically explain what to do?

Any friendly direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If their versioning is paired in a way that for every version `x.y.z` of tomcat, you have an `x.y.z` of tomcast-jdbc, then I would assume that their versions are linked, and thus should be kept in sync as you noted.

Comment: what version of tomcat you are trying to use?

Comment: @Rogue, that is my assumption as well, it seems like the correlation between the tomcat server and tomcat-jdbc versions is high, but you know what they say about assumptions...

Comment: @ConstantineCh, we are using the 9.0.65 version of tomcat.  Most likely updating to the latest version of 9 (9.0.70) soonish.

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point of the question (if so, apologies), but don't you just use whichever `tomcat-jdbc` JAR file (tomcat-jdbc.jar) comes bundled with the version of Tomcat you downloaded and are using? There is no need to make a choice - is there? Apart from that, I'm not sure you would choose `tomcat-jdbc` these days (unless for legacy reasons) as Tomcat also comes bundled with the newer `tomcat-dbcp` (the [default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69662886/12567365))- or you can use a 3rd party pool provider.

Comment: @andrewJames good question.  I will have to do some research on why we have the tomcat-jdbc as a dependency in our application.  Thanks for the friendly direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come to find out after some friendly direction by @andrewJames, the tomcat-jdbc library is provided by the Tomcat instance itself.

We most likely had the tomcat-jdbc in our pom.xml because it stopped red-lines in our Spring xml configuration files with missing Class names and attributes.

The person that originally added the tomcat-jdbc library to our pom should have scoped the library as 'provided'.

Then after a bit more research into Connection Pools we decided to switch to [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) due to its small package size and speed improvements over tomcat-jdbc.